# mime type of image and video taken on android phone

Tags: android

If i use android phone to capture image and video whether it is the default camera app or other android camera app, is it safe to assume the image mime type will be 'jpg'? and video mime type be 'mp4 or 3gp'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output format could be changed, so no it is not safe to assume anything on image or video mime type.

Answer (score 0):

i presume you may use * to put it as generic

egs: "image/*"